# React and material UI: No cursor in input box, can't enter values

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, cursor-position

I use Material UI to have an input field that takes in a certain amount of value in $$. The problem I'm having is, the input box is always disabled. I can see the onClick working in the console, but there is no pointer, and the user can't enter any values.

```
               <Input
                  variants={{
                    name: 'dollar',
                    validationType: 'dollar',
                    label: 'Dollars',
                    placeholder: '$ 0.00',
                    switchAriaLabel: 'Switch to Amount',
                  }}
                  selected={{
                    name: 'dollar',
                    rawValue: '',
                    value: 0
                  }}
                  value={selectedCashAmount}
                  onChange={amount => setSelectedWithdrawalSplitCashAmount(amount)}
                  errorText={_.get(this.state.rolloverErrors, 'text')}
                  id="EnterInstallmentt"
/>
```

The box appears with $ 0.00 as placeholder but nothing happens when it's clicked. Any ideas on how to overcome this? Thanks!

Comment: Full code would help (include the hander function).

Comment: @keikai the onChange calls an action and updates the value in the redux store...Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of value would you like to get? Looks like you mixed up `text` input field and `select` field. The problem is rooted in using `onClick` and `onChange` functions simultaneously.

However, you're looking for the [`Autocomplete` input field](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) which allows you to use both select lists and text input value.

Comment: The value I would like to get is the one that the user enters in the text field, right now the UI is not letting the user any value, which is what I'm trying to figure out. It's just an input field, without any selected dropdowns. The "Selected" here is just a prop. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. So you could remove useless props according to `Input` APIs (https://material-ui.com/api/input/): 
```<Input
        value={selectedCashAmount}
        onChange={amount => setSelectedWithdrawalSplitCashAmount(amount)}
        errorText={!selectedCashAmount}
        id="EnterInstallmentt"
/>
```

To be more specific, you can use TextField (https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/)